# how to embed a flash movie with a full player in a web page?

Tags: flash

i want to play some swf movie in my page and i need a player with stop/pause/play and forward/backward button.
what is the best option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider uploading the movie to a video hosting site such as youtube or vimeo and then embed their player. They will have a more reliable site, have easily embedded players, and they put a lot of work into their flash player.

Comment: thanks but i need something that doesn't need to upload movies on the other servers.

Comment: Well, the only free video player I know of is flowplayer, but never having used it myself I can't really comment on how good it is. I believe they have a free version and a commercial licence as well, so it may be worth checking out their demo page - http://flowplayer.org/demos/installation/index.html